# Open source program that can run Windows processes remotely (from a linux machine)?

Tags: linux, remote-access

Is there a Linux program that can run processes that exist on a remote Windows machine?

E.g. I have several [.dtsx](https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/dtsx) files on a Windows Server 2012 machine that are executed via Windows Task Scheduler, but I would like to have these files executed from an [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/index.html) job instead. My idea would be to access the remote execution program from a bash script on the linux machine as part of an Airflow workflow.

If there is anything similar to this or if this is a use-case that other have resolved some other way, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I know, [Ansible can control Windows machines over WinRM](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows.html). You can use Ansible or look how it implemented. (**UPD1:** Thanks to lampShadesDrifter. [pywinrm](http://github.com/diyan/pywinrm) which is supposedly used by Ansible.)
2. Look like cross-platform the [PowerShell Core](http://ttps://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) can control remote
   host.

**UPD2:**

3. Try use [pstools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) under wine. (but it not open source solution)

Comment: Had heard of Ansible before and looks interesting. Others finding this post can see here for more info (https://www.ansible.com/resources/get-started) (appears that Ansible is free, but there are non-free versions / integrations as well). Also found python package `pywinrm` (https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm) which is supposedly used by Ansible. Haven't tested it, but *looks* simple enough.

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter WinRM in general is pretty simple, once you have it set up properly.  Getting it to the point that it's properly set up on the client system though is not exactly trivial.